# A combinatorial identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that there is some $p$ such that $\forall i\in  \{1,\ldots,n\}, |X_i|=p$.
>
> Suppose as well that there is some $q$ such that  $i\neq j \implies |X_i \cap X_j|=q$.
>
> Prove that $p^2=p+(n-1)q$.

I tried something with an incidence matrix and it boils down to proving that its determinant is $p^2(p-q)^{(n-1)/2}$, but I can't prove that

**EDIT**: The problem as it is stated is flawed. It must be added that each $i$ appears in exactly $p$ of the $X_j$

Comment: Can you construct an example in which $n-1\neq p$ and $q\neq p-1$?

Comment: what if all the $X_i$'s equal to $\{1\}$, then $p=1$ and $q=1$ and the conclusion is not true.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that all columns of the incidence matrix have same weight (as the rows). I'm not sure if that's necessary (or true!)

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle this is how the problem is stated. However, it may be safe to assume all the $X_i$ are distinct.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I've written some thoughts, seems the conclusion is true if and only if the assumption made by user133281 is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prove $p^2 \le p+(n-1)q$ in general and the equality holds if and only if @user133281's assumption is true:

Define a matrix $A =(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij} = 1$ if $j \in X_i$ and otherwise $a_{ij} = 0$, then the given condition can be written as

$$AA^{T} =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p & q & \cdots & \cdots &q \\
q & p & q & \cdots & q  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
q & q & q & \cdots & p \end{array} \right) $$

Denote $b_i = \sharp\{j, i\in X_j\}$, then by multiplying both sides of the above matrix identity by the vector $v = (1,1,1,\cdots, 1)^T$ and computing the elements' sum of both results, we can show $$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 = n(p+(n-1)q)$$
(Remark that $A^T v = (b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n)^T$ and the elements of $A(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n)^T$ sums up to $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$)

And obviously we also have $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = np$.

Since $(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 )(n) \ge (\sum_{i=1}^n b_i )^2$, we have $ n^2(p+(n-1)q) \geq n^2p^2$, so $p^2 = p+(n-1)q$ if and only if all $b_i$'s are equal, i.e. $b_i = p, \forall i$

Comment: I agree that $v^{T}AA^{T}v=n(p+(n-1)q)$ but I can't understand why it should also be equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$. Instead, it rather seems that it equal to $np^2$. Indeed the coefficient of $v^{T}AA^{T}v$ is $\displaystyle\sum_i \sum_j \sum_k A_{k,i}A_{j,i}=\sum_i(\sum_j A_{j,i})(\sum_k A_{k,i})=\sum_i p^2 = np^2$. From there it follows that $np^2=n(p+(n-1)q)$ and the problem is solved.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I was not saying $v^TAA^Tv = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$, I mean that the elements of $AA^Tv$ adds up to $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$

Comment: So yes, you're saying that $v^TAA^Tv = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$ :P

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I see. But you are using the assumption that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji} = p$ right? so this is the case where all $b_i$'s are equal

Comment: No, $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}$ is the number of "$1$" on the i-th column, that is to say the cardinal of $X_i$, that is $p$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Sorry I made a mistake, I've interchanged the index $i$ and $j$ in the definition of $a_{ij}$. Just think that, if there is a proof for the conclusion in general case, it contradicts my comment below the question.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with your proof now. Nicely done (love the Cauchy Schwarz).

Answer (score 2):

This is a proof for the case that each $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is contained in $p$ of the $X_j$. As pointed out in the comments, the result is not true in general otherwise.

Let us count the number of triplets $(i,j,k) \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}^3$ with the property that $i \neq j$, $k \in X_i$ and $k \in X_j$.

Choosing $i$ and $j$ first and then choosing $k \in X_i \cap X_j$ can be done in $n(n-1)q$ ways.

Choosing $i$ first, then $k \in X_i$ and then $j$ such that $k \in X_j$ can be done in $np(p-1)$ ways, because $k$ is contained in $p-1$ sets other than $X_i$.

We conclude that both $n(n-1)q$ and $np(p-1)$ count the number of triplets, hence $n(n-1)q=np(p-1)$. This yields $(n-1)q = p(p-1)$, as desired.